# fit and/or backgrounds does not work as expected in tikz-qtree

Tags: backgrounds, tikz-qtree, shapes, fit

I am drawing a tree using `tikz-qtree` and want to draw `backgrounds` for two groups of nodes: the left group consisting of `l, l1, l2` and the right group consisting of `r, rl, l3, l4, l5`. However, as shown in the figure below, the node `c` is also in the right background rectangle.

How to draw a background rectangle consisting of only `r, rl, l3, l4, l5`?

[image: 2-tree-LR]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 25pt, sibling distance = 15pt,   edge from parent/.style= {
      draw, edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}]   \tikzset{every tree node/.style = {align = center, circle, draw, fill = red!40},
      leaf/.style = {fill = teal!40}}

      \Tree [.\node[](c){$c$}; 
              [.\node[](l){$l$}; 
                [.\node[leaf](l1){$l_1$}; ]
                [.\node[leaf](l2){$l_2$}; ]
              ]
              [.\node[](r){$r$};
                [.\node[](rl){$rl$};
                  [.\node[leaf](l3){$l_3$}; ] 
                  [.\node[leaf](l4){$l_4$}; ]
                ] 
                [.\node[leaf](l5){$l_5$}; ]
              ]       
      ]

      \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit = (l) (l1) (l2)] {};   
      \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit = (r) (rl) (l3) (l4) (l5)] {}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to name the node something other than `r`. Below, I use `3r` for no particular reason.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 25pt, sibling distance = 15pt,   edge from parent/.style= {
    draw, edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}]   \tikzset{every tree node/.style = {align = center, circle, draw, fill = red!40},
    leaf/.style = {fill = teal!40}}

  \Tree [.\node[](c){$c$}; 
  [.\node[](l){$l$}; 
  [.\node[leaf](l1){$l_1$}; ]
  [.\node[leaf](l2){$l_2$}; ]
  ]
  [.\node[](3r){$r$};
  [.\node[](rl){$rl$};
  [.\node[leaf](l3){$l_3$}; ] 
  [.\node[leaf](l4){$l_4$}; ]
  ] 
  [.\node[leaf](l5){$l_5$}; ]
  ]       
  ]

  \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit = (l) (l1) (l2)] {};   
  \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit = (3r) (rl) (l3) (l4) (l5)] {}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: more fittingly fitted <code>fit</code>s]

However, I don't know why either. That said, I am guessing that `(r)` is the root of the tree, since you can use this node without ever naming anything `r`. For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 25pt, sibling distance = 15pt,   edge from parent/.style= {
    draw, edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}]   \tikzset{every tree node/.style = {align = center, circle, draw, fill = red!40},
    leaf/.style = {fill = teal!40}}

  \Tree [.\node[](c){$c$}; 
  [.\node[](l){$l$}; 
  [.\node[leaf](l1){$l_1$}; ]
  [.\node[leaf](l2){$l_2$}; ]
  ]
  [.\node[](3r){$r$};
  [.\node[](rl){$rl$};
  [.\node[leaf](l3){$l_3$}; ] 
  [.\node[leaf](l4){$l_4$}; ]
  ] 
  [.\node[leaf](l5){$l_5$}; ]
  ]       
  ]

  \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit = (l) (l1) (l2)] {};   
  \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit = (3r) (rl) (l3) (l4) (l5)] {}; 
  \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit = (r) (rl) (l3) (l4) (l5)] {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces perfectly sensible, if unexpected, output rather than the expected error:

[image: ill-fitting <code>fit</code>s]

which strongly suggests that `r` names the root node or, probably, a coordinate or invisible node at the root of the tree.

Comment: Nice catch. I looked through the `tiki-qtree` code but didn't see anything that would indicate a named root.

Comment: @AlanMunn I looked, too, but it is hard when you're looking for such a popular letter.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but as a workaround you can add an explicit coordinate relative to `(r)` to use instead:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, shapes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 25pt, sibling distance = 15pt,   edge from parent/.style= {
      draw, edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}]   \tikzset{every tree node/.style = {align = center, circle, draw, fill = red!40},
      leaf/.style = {fill = teal!40}}

      \Tree [.\node[](c){$c$}; 
              [.\node[](l){$l$}; 
                [.\node[leaf](l1){$l_1$}; ]
                [.\node[leaf](l2){$l_2$}; ]
              ]
              [.\node[](r){$r$};
                [.\node[](rl){$rl$};
                  [.\node[leaf](l3){$l_3$}; ] 
                  [.\node[leaf](l4){$l_4$}; ]
                ] 
                [.\node[leaf](l5){$l_5$}; ]
              ]       
      ]
      \coordinate (rr) at ($(r)-(0,.6)$);
      \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit = (l) (l1) (l2)] {};   
      \node () [draw, dashed, cyan, rounded corners, fit =  (rr) (rl) (l3) (l4) (l5) ] {}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Why `-(0,.6)`? Anyway, it is too much work to do it your way :-).